# can I proxy AWS API Gateway WebSocket to WebSocket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

Currently I am using the API Gateway as a kind of proxy to provide https simply

```
https://random-aws-name.com => http://my-domain.com
```

The route was `$default`

The integration setup is `HTTP ANY -> http://my-domain.com`

I am now having to setup an Websocket server on my domain that is already listening at ws://my-domain.com. I can connect directly to this socket but not using the AWS API Gateway

```
wss://random-aws-name.com => ws://my-domain.com
```

Currently I an getting unexpected error 400, using wscat

I tried to enable API gateway logging and do not see any log arrive

Comment: What is the exception message? Also do you see the request reaching the logs of `ws://my-domain.com` service?

Comment: The message is Error: unexpected server response (400)
I do not see any log at ws://my-domain.com but I can not be completely sure if it is due to API gateway or any proxy in the middle that refuse the connection

Comment: For further reference https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1370

Comment: @qkhanhpro, I have the same problem. Here's the exception server side. `the client is not using the websocket protocol: 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header"`. 

Most probably, API Gateway strips off the websocket headers in the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO, AWS API Gateway is only able to provide a wss end point and route requests to **HTTP backends only**. If we already have a backend websocket server, I don't see an option in AWS API Gateway to perform such routing (Although I would be glad to be proven wrong as I have such a requirement myself.).

I actually tried giving wss:// url as the Endpoint URL but I got an error while deploying the API saying `Invalid HTTP endpoint specified for URI`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the API Gateway you are currently using is not a WebSocket API, but rather an HTTP API or REST API. API Gateway has different flavors. You pick a flavor when you deploy. The flavor that you deployed is most likely not the flavor that supports WebSocket connections.

According to this documentation page, proxied WebSocket connections may only be one-way (note in blue box at bottom of page): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-routes-integrations.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache2 como Proxy.

<VirtualHost *:443>

```
    ServerAdmin pedro.casas@********
    DocumentRoot /var/www/**************
    ServerAlias dominio.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/****.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/****.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/****.ca-bundle

    
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass "/wss/"  "ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/"                      
    ProxyPassReverse  "/wss/"  "ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/"
```